# Yii2 Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to get data from a model.

```
$profile = Profile::findOne(['user_id'=>$appointment->user_id]);
$diabetes = $profile->diabetes;
```

I get an error **Trying to get property 'diabetes' of non-object**.

Tried to check the availability of data through:

```
$profile->getAttributes(['diabetes'])
```

Data present! But I can't use any data from the model in any way. What's my mistake?

Comment: `$profile` is empty. try checking `$profile` object first.

Comment: $profile not empty, checked

Comment: That error literary means that whatever is in `$profile` property is not an object. The `ActiveRecord::findOne()` method can only return `object` or `null`, so if php says it's not object it can only be null. Unless you've overriden `findOne()` method. If that's not a case then you've probably tried to check it in some wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

If you avoid this error please try bellow code

```
 $profile = Profile::findOne(['user_id'=>$appointment->user_id]);
 if (!empty($profile)) {
   $diabetes = $profile->diabetes;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use findOne please do :

```
$profile = Profile::findOne($appointment->user_id);
```

if you want to use find :

```
$profile = Profile::find()->where(['user_id' => $appointment->user_id])->one();
```

You can find doc here [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#findOne()-detail)
Hope this helping